# Java regular expression with special characters

Tags: java, regex

I have a text string in java ["1234","abd df"], I need to write a regular expression in Java which capture both elements

first element=1234,
second element=abd df

I am using following regex

```
\\[\\"(.*?)\\",\\".*?\\"\\]
```

But above doesn't work properly, Actually both elements could be numeric or alphabetic, Can someone guide me to the proper regex string?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This would match them separately:

```
"[^"]*"
```

And this would match the comma-separated quoted strings and capture the quoted parts:

```
"([^"]*)","([^"]*)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is pretty close.

Made minor change to it to show that i works.

Your regex:

```
\\[\\"(.*?)\\",\\".*?\\"\\]
```

After minor change:

```
\\[\"(.*?)\",\"(.*?)\"\\]
```

Regex in context:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "[\"1234\",\"abd df\"]";

    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\[\"(.*?)\",\"(.*?)\"\\]").matcher(input);

    if(matcher.find()) {
        System.out.printf("Element 1: '%s'%n", matcher.group(1));
        System.out.printf("Element 2: '%s'%n", matcher.group(2));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Element 1: '1234'
Element 2: 'abd df'
```